# Chrome - Jquery .submit()

Tags: jquery, submit

The .submit() function doesn't seem to be working for me in Chrome. I've made sure that the name of my submit button isn't submit. Here's the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('option').click(function() {
            $('form#analytics').submit();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code since im not sure what your calling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting a form to submit when the user changes a `<select>` element, you might want:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('form#analytics').submit();
});
```